# Need recommendatins on a Java open source project for an academic study

Tags: java, open-source, testing

I'm looking for a Java open source project for an academic study on test cases.
I need a project with 20-40 KLOC and at least a 100 JUnit tests.
A project that was developed using TDD methodology is prefered. 
Something that I can drop in eclipse and run all the tests with minimal overhead for setups.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 5):

It's amusing that you say "drop in eclipse", as some parts of eclipse were written with TDD and have relatively large numbers of LOC.  You may want to go that route.  I know, for example, that the Eclipse-based FORTRAN IDE project is one such endeavor.

Comment: +1 - I didn't even consider any of the Eclipse projects. That is absolutely brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

The Spring framework?   May be too large perhaps.

There are any number of projects you can use.  You could look at the BouncyCastle encryption library.
http://bouncycastle.org/java.html

Comment: +1 - Spring would be a very good example.

Answer (score 0):

To help with your search, you could have a look at Koders (http://koders.com/), the source code search engine. They have information about LOC for open source projects.